# Setting initial form field value for superuser in Django

Tags: python, django

I have form for writing comments and I want "author" field to be "admin" for default if the logged user is superuser. I also want to hide the "author" field form for the superuser.

model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField()
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def ___str___(self):
        return self.text
```

form:

```
class CreateComment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ["author", "text"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateComment, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

ChatGPT suggested me to add this to the form:

```
if kwargs.get("user").is_superuser:
    self.fields["author"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields["author"].initial = "admin"
```

but I got this error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/14/
>
> Django Version: 4.1.7 Python Version: 3.9.7 Installed Applications:
> ['mainapp.apps.MainappConfig',  'django.contrib.admin',
> 'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Tomasz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 56, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Tomasz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Tomasz\Desktop\myblog\mainapp\views.py", line 41, in
> article_view
> form = CreateComment()   File "C:\Users\Tomasz\Desktop\myblog\mainapp\forms.py", line 23, in
> **init**
> if kwargs.get("user").is_superuser:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /14/ Exception Value: 'NoneType'
> object has no attribute 'is_superuser'

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Include your view. It sounds like you're not passing the user as a kwarg to the form & that would need to happen from the view where you include the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to fix your `Comment` model, instead of storing a string relate the `User` model, and resolve the information you want on render (template).

But, to answer your question. Basically you need to [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) the form without commiting, which creates a model instance. Then, you manually set the other fields:

views.py

```py
def article_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateComment(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.article = article
            comment.author = "admin" if request.user.is_superuser else form.cleaned_data["author"]
            comment.publication_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
            comment.save()
    else:
        form = CreateComment()

    context = {
        "article": article, 
        "form": form, 
        "comments": article.comment_set.all()
    }
    return render(request, "article/detail.html", context)
```